# to search for files with 2 (full or partial) keywords content (txt files) in a folder and sub folder and files with specific filename

Tags: wildcards, ripgrep

I just want to share this, and hoping will get more similar tool.

I got a directory of text files.. i need to search for the files with 2 (partial) words in it.. the keywords are in random order, but on a same line.

So far, i can use this:

```
$ rg -i '\w*keyword1\w*.*\w*keyword2\w*|\w*keyword2\w*.*\w*keyword1\w*' --glob '*.txt' --line-number -l /path/to/search

$ rg -g '*.txt' -l -i 'keyword1.*keyword2|keyword2.*keyword1' /path/to/search
```

Both of these can do the same job.

Anybody have other that can do the same job ? Pls do share. I found myself need this quite often to locate the proper file..

However i don't know how to search file that filename is 2 keywords that are not in order.
How about searching for filename with 2 keyword that is not in order ?
Example:
weirdfilename_key1Nkey3Nkey2etc.txt
search among huge database for file with which name only remember consist of  "key2" and "key3" in it, but not sure the order..

Answer (score 0):

Maybe:

```
rg -iPlg '*{Key1*Key2,Key2*Key1}*.txt' '^(?=.*keyword1)(?=.*keyword2)' dir
```

With `-P`, we get PCRE regexps that have look ahead operators so we can match `^` the start of the line provided it's followed by any number of characters followed by `keyword1` and that it's also followed by any number of characters followed by `keyword2`.

`-g '*{Key1*Key2,Key2*Key1}*.txt'` is short for `-g '*Key1*Key2*.txt -g '*Key2*Key1*.txt'` where that `{x,y}` similar to csh brace expansion is a ripgrep extension to standard shell glob patterns.